# Trouble subtracting letters from str

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to retrieve an arrival time for migrating geese, so it will give the correct time from an input.

Please ignore the x = 1100 value, I'm creating an input but this is just a place holder. Also the 24-7 is the time difference of the destination & rest.

```
import datetime
import re

x = 1100
alpha = list(str(x))
varhours = int(alpha[0]+alpha[1])
varminutes = int(alpha[2]+alpha[3])

if (varminutes>59 and x<0000 and x>2400):
    print('please enter correct time format; hhmm') 

starttime = datetime.timedelta(hours= varhours, minutes= varminutes)

speed = 50
duration = 24-7 +(3277/speed)
endtime = datetime.timedelta(hours=duration)
timetaken = endtime-starttime
print (re.sub("days", " ",)('time taken: '+str(timetaken))
```

I keep getting an EOF error. I'm expecting the output to remove the "days" portion and just give the arrival time rather than "3 days, 22:11:43".

Answer (score 0):

Try this for line 18:

```
print (re.sub("days", " ", 'time taken: '+str(timetaken)))
```

You should get the desired result!